# Django CBV : Download PDF document from media

Tags: django

I would like to download pdf file in my view but I don't overcome to display browser window which let to download my file.

The `downloadPDF` function seems to work well but nothing appears on my browser.

This is my class :

```
class TokenDownloadView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/token.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['token'] = self.kwargs['token']
        token = context['token']

        download = Download.objects.get(token__iexact=token)
        upload_doc = Document.objects.get(id=download.pub_id).upload

        if download and download.expiration_date > now:
            print("token valide jusqu'à : " + str(download.expiration_date))
            print("il est actuellement : " + str(now))
            print(' ==> Token existe et valide <==')
            messages.success(self.request, 'Vous allez télécharger le document')

            self.downloadPDF(upload_doc)

        if download and download.expiration_date < now:
            print("token valide jusqu'à : " + str(download.expiration_date))
            print("il est actuellement : " + str(now))
            print('==> Token existe mais a expiré <==')
            messages.error(self.request, 'Document non téléchargé : la session a expiré')

        return context

    def downloadPDF(self, upload_doc):

        from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
        from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound

        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = upload_doc
        if fs.exists(filename):
            with fs.open(filename) as pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
                return response
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound('The requested pdf was not found in our server.')
```

I miss something in my class which could let to download my pdf ?

***EDIT :***

I edited my class in order to convert `get_context_data()` to `get()` method. It seems to work but I would like to get your mind :

```
class TokenDownloadView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/token.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        context = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

        token = self.kwargs['token']

        download = Download.objects.get(token__iexact=token)
        document_title = Document.objects.get(id=download.pub_id).title
        upload_doc = Document.objects.get(id=download.pub_id).upload

        if download and download.expiration_date > now:
            print("Token is valid until : " + str(download.expiration_date))
            print("Now : " + str(now))
            print(' ==> Token exists and valid <==')
            messages.success(self.request, 'You are going to download document(s)')

            resp = self.downloadPDF(upload_doc, document_title)

        if download and download.expiration_date < now:
            print("Token is valid until : " + str(download.expiration_date))
            print("Now : " + str(now))
            print('==> Token exists but has expired <==')
            messages.error(self.request, 'Session of 10 minutes has expired - Please download document(s) one more time')
            return render(request, self.template_name)

        return resp

    def downloadPDF(self, upload_doc, document_title):

        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = upload_doc
        if fs.exists(filename):
            with fs.open(filename) as pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s.pdf"' % document_title
                return response
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound('The requested pdf was not found in our server.')
```

Comment: you have to overide the `get method`  rather than `get context data`

Comment: `get_context_data` should always return a dictionary. It doesn't make sense to return a response. It looks odd to call `messages.success()` or `messages.error()` there as well. Finally, you call `self.downloadPDF(upload_doc)` instead of `return self.downloadPDF(upload_doc)`, so your view doesn't do anything with the result. I would rethink whether you really want to use class-based-views here - a function based view might be easier to reason about.

Comment: The method `get_context_data` should return a context dictionary that is used to render the template. Now you're calling your function `downloadPDF` which is returning an `HttpResponse` but not assigning that response to anything. Instead, you should move all of this code to the `get()` method and  try assigning `self.downloadPDF()` to a `response` variable that you return (instead of the template rendering)

Comment: @Alasdair I changed my method. It seems to work but I would like your mind about my modification.

Comment: @NakulNarayanan too

Comment: @dirkgroten too

Comment: As I suggested before, I don't think you should be using a class based view here, it makes it harder to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Alasdair Oh ok ! I have a doubt between : keep CBV with `get` method as I displayed before (it seems to work with download method) or convert from zero this class to function based view.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `context` (and it shouldn't be `super().get()` because that returns an `HttpResponse`). Look at the [source code](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/) for the `TemplateView` to better understand what's going on. Agree with @Alasdair, you should switch to a function-based view here.

Comment: Ok thank you with your both answers. I will work on to switch to a function-based view here !

Answer (score 1):

You call the `downloadPDF` but you ignore its return value. You would need to return the result of calling that method. However, this will *not* work because you cannot return a response from `get_context_data`; that method, as the name implies, must return a dictionary context and not a response.

You need to move this code into the `get` method.

Comment: Ok, so I need to move `get_context_data` inside a `get` method or I need to replace `get_context_data` by `get` method ? I understand that both method don't return the same thing, `dict` for the first one and `response` for the second one.

Comment: I changed my code following your advices and I would like to know if it's right now ? It seems to work fine anyway